# Как правильно вернуть значение запроса?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, запрос

Как вернуть значение id в переменную из запроса:

```
$prepared[$product['id']]=array(
                "name"=>$product["name"],
                "image_url"=>$url_crop_small,
                "url"=>$product['url'],
            );
```

Шаблон вывода (Вывод имени товара):

```
<td class="s-product-name" title="{$product.name}">
<div>{$product.name|htmlspecialchars}<i class="shortener"></i></div>
</td>
```

Comment: Куда идёт/приходит запрос?

Comment: И как понять "вернуть" значение ? Он куда то пропадает?

Comment: как правильно тогда вывести id?

Comment: Обновил, добавил шаблон вывода

Comment: Запрос идет в bd webasyst